# WebSphere/Rational Application Developer(RAD), tmp directory for builds?

Tags: java, websphere, rad

I am trying to build my java classes but they aren't going to the directory defined in the WEB-INF/classes directory.

RAD will build but the class files aren't output.  And they also aren't output to the:

.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core

Directory either.   There must be a temp place for the classes?  Do you know where they are?

The IDE doesn't show errors, so I am assuming RAD is doing some kind of internal build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by disabling the Java Builder and then enabling the builder and the classes are now outputting.  Strange

Answer (score 2):

Check your project's build path. This is likely available by right-clicking the project, selecting "Properties" and then navigating to the "Java Build Path." From there select the "Source" tab and view/modify the "Default output folder." This should indicate where your class files are being built, and you can modify the directory there, if desired.

Note that these instructions are for Eclipse, but since RAD is based on Eclipse, the instructions are likely similar, if not identical.

Comment: Yea, RAD won't build to the class directory defined in the build path.  It is a bug somehwere.  I used the solution I listed below.